# Why I'm not getting an error when use undefined index?

Tags: php, c++, indexing

I'm from `php` and when I define something like this:

```
$a = array();
echo $a[586];
```

I will get a notice about undefined index.

Meanwhile at `c++` I can do this:

```
map<int, string> my_map;
cout << "Map is: " << my_map[34535];

string sentence = "acdefb s";
cout << "Letter is: " << sentence[15];
```

And I won't get any error.

Why it's not possible at `php` and possible at `c++`?

Comment: Funny thing, PHP acting stricter than C++.

Comment: In C++ `operator [](keytype)` for a map will *add* a default-constructed instance of your map's value-type if there isn't one already present at that index. if you don't want this behaviour, use `.find(keytype)` instead, and check the resulting iterator against `my_map.end()`.

Comment: `sentence[34535]` is out of bounds and would crash your program.

Comment: @Rapptz Sorry, copy-paste, changed on another value.

Comment: @viakondratiuk still out of bounds, which means it's undefined behaviour which on most implementations would still crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because PHP and C++ are two radically different languages with radically different semantics.  When using the `[]` operator with an `std::map` object in C++, a new element is inserted into the map if the key does not already exist within the map.  In PHP, this is not the case.

As for your second example with `std::string sentance`, it is ***not*** valid to use the `[]` operator with an invalid index (an index which is `>= sentance.length()`) on an `std::string` in C++.  You may not get any "error", because the result of using an invalid index with `std::string` is **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**, meaning that anything can happen.  One common result on modern platforms is a Segmentation Fault/Access Violation, which generally will crash your program.

With `std::string` you can use `std::string::at()` instead of the `[]` operator if you want protection against undefined behavior.  The `at` function does a bounds check and throws `std::out_of_range` if you use an invalid index.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a language that is written for performance. If you have an array with 10 million items, and legally walk through all items, it would add time to check if every one of those 10M accesses are valid or not. As a side-effect, you also can, under the "right" circumstances walk outside the range that is valid without it being detected. It's most likely, that if you get too far outside the valid range, SOMETHING will go wrong. But the C++ doesn't guarantee either that it does go wrong, or what else may happen - it's something called "undefined behaviour" - UB for short.

In the case of the map, it doesn't do what you think it does anyways, it actually creates a new empty element in your container, and then prints that.

Therefore, in cases where you have "unknown" index - for example a function that takes an index as a parameter, it's a good idea to check that the value is within range - at least in debug builds of the code. You can use for example `assert()` to do that:

```
// v is a vector, or string, or some such. 
assert(index < v.size);
```

This will "break" your program any time you go outside the valid range. In release builds, `assert` compiles to nothing, so there is no extra code when you run the code in a proper release build.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the sentence string at a value than is greater than the length of your string will nearly always cause a segmentation fault. If this code is in fact running without an error it is because 'fortunately' this memory address doesn't not resolve to something that is not owned by the process. Instead you will just get garbage.